# Does deleting a lot of a rows in a transaction hurt with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Say there are 3 tasks:

1. Insert rows to `table_a`.
2. Select rows in `table_a`, and select scope may cover the entire table.
3. Delete rows from `table_a`:

```sql
delete from table_a where timestamp < certain_time
```

As the delete condition is based on timestamp, sometime it may delete huge amount of rows. And as other tables have foreign keys refer to `table_a` with `on delete cascade`, a delete transaction may take long time.

From [Postgres Table lock on delete query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63337280/postgres-table-lock-on-delete-query), looks like `delete` won't impact `insert`. But will `delete` impact `select`? `delete` locks rows to be deleted, and `select` may search over those rows.

Will keeping delete transaction small be necessary and safer, such as:

```sql
delete from table_a where id in (
    select id from table_a timestamp < certain_time limit 1000
)
```

*NOTE: in my case, it's NOT super important to delete rows as early as possible.*

Comment: Read this [Concurrency](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) in particular *13.2.1. Read Committed Isolation Level*. The answer to this and a lot more are there.

Comment: It won't directly block them, but cascading deletes can generate huge amounts of random IO, and that can then compete with the IO needed to fulfill the selects.  They can also take a huge number of transient "lightweight" locks, which cumulatively can slow down anything also trying to touch the same data pages.